# How to send a string to a website in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, web

Here is my scenario: I want to create an android application which allows me to search bus information once I entered the bus code. Bus information is retrieved from this website:  http://www.stm.info/English/a-somm.htm

I intend to create an activity with a TextView and a Button. This TextView allows user to insert the bus code. When user clicks to the button, the bus code is sent to the above website. After that, information about this bus is displayed in a new activity. Also, information is retrieved from the website via the search function of this site.

I do not know which technologies, which method is suit with what I want. Can anybody help me, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most of us wouldn't know that website. Does it provide an API? Does it provide data as JSON? XML? Would you have to do web scraping? More information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You question can be divided into 2 different question**, the first one is how to preform a search and get the result, this one is quite easy. you will need to send a GET request to the following website with the following URL, note that you should change the last parameter to your bus code:

```
http://www2.stm.info/horaires/frmResult.aspx?Langue=En&Arret=BusCodeHere
```

The second thing you need to do is to get the respone from the server (which is obviously HTML code) and parse it in to an Array/table/SQL and finally display it your GUI

Google : html parsing with java

In case the website has an API, this task can be much easier. just ask the api for the search result, and parse it easily via JSON/XML parser class